# BASH: SQLite3 .backup command

Tags: sqlite, backup

I'm trying to back up my db using a BASH script while having an application use it at the same time.

The application is not a heavy write application.

I've seen different solutions on SO, but want to confirm the correct way.  I want users the ability to read at any time during the backup, writing is not a concern since I do all the writing (blog app).

Are there any dangers in corruption using:

```
sqlite3 /var/www/ghost/content/data/ghost.db <<EOF
.timeout 20000
.backup tmp.db
EOF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.backup` command uses SQLite's backup API, which is designed for online backups.

As long as you do not do have [broken hardware or software](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) (which has nothing to with backups and would affect any writes), this will work fine.